# Python: Write a list of numeric values on a single row with a repeated format

Tags: python

I have a list of numeric values, let's say:

```
draw6 = [0.13234, 0.14235, 0.15235, 0.16233]
```

I want to write the values in this to a file, the same way the print statement below does:

```
print ('{:10.4f} '*len(draw6)).format(*draw6)
```

The print statement works, but I need to use a write statement because I want to write to a file. The write statement doesn't have "format" as an attribute.

So

```
file.write('{:10.4f} '*len(draw6)).format(*draw6)
```

does not work.

How do I mimic the print statement in a write statement? I've tried tens of options but none of them work. I was very happy when the print statement worked, but then very disappointed when it didn't work with write.

Many thanks,
Gijs

Comment: I thought you formatted a string, not a function or method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
s = ('{:10.4f} '*len(draw6)).format(*draw6)    # s = '    0.1323     0.1424     0.1524     0.1623'
file.write(s)
```